# Deserialization failed: invalid length for a base-64 char array

Tags: xml, visual-studio, debugging, ssrs-2008

I am using visual studio and when I attempt to run an XML code, I get an error message of 'invalid length for a Base-64 char array at line 7901, position 91'.

The XML code is too long for me to include in this post so I have included line 7901 that was flagged with the error. Can anyone advise on how I fix this?

```
cBgV62T5HDL51JQk2ptvVLRt33R4+c55PMY0lOPK4RUdG7NJJLR7PTUKKKK9w8EKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKAP//Z</ImageData>
```

Comment: Try dropping the //Z at the end.

Comment: your suggestion worked, Michael! thank you ever so much.

Answer (score 0):

The (allegedly) base64 value has a spurious "//Z" at the end.